# Menu sort by year field

Tags: 7, nodes, views

I'm created a content type and have got field_year. I want, sort my contents by field_year on my sidebar. How can I do this?

Comment: Are your field `field_year` integer? http://i.imgur.com/u4Wc4.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you have added views tag [views-filters](/questions/tagged/views-filters), so, I think, you don't mind to list your content with [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views).
If your field `field_year` is integer it is really easy to sort your content:
[image]

Some notes:

1. If you need block, just create Block display in Views. New block will be available on `admin/structure/block` page.
2. Add fields you want. Here I'm showing only title as a link to the original piece of content.
3. Remove all sorts and add your own by clicking on the *Add* button. It's very easy to find your field by it's name or machine name.

Result:

[image]

Yes, `active` class is added automatically. 
Views module has tons of settings. To learn more please take a look at [“Taming the Beast: Learn Views with NodeOne”](http://nodeone.se/en/node/20) series.

Comment: Please, explain why it was downvoted.